# How do I create a `CfnOutput` that is a list of values?

Tags: python, aws-cdk

All of the [examples](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/tree/master/python) use the `CfnOutput` class.  But the [`CfnOutput`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.core/CfnOutput.html?highlight=cfnoutput#aws_cdk.core.CfnOutput) class only accepts a `str` for the `value` parameter.

This doesn't work for that reason:

```py
from aws_cdk import CfnOutput, Stack, aws_ec2
from constructs import Construct

class MyVpc(Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id)

        vpc = aws_ec2.Vpc.from_lookup(scope, construct_id, is_default=True)
        
        CfnOutput(self, "private_subnets", values=vpc.private_subnets)
        CfnOutput(self, "public_subnets", values=vpc.public_subnets)
```

The error being

```
Argument of type "List[ISubnet]" cannot be assigned to parameter "value" of type "str" in function
```

As the code snippet shows, I'd like to export a list of VPC subnets from the AWS-created default VPC in order to pass into to an another stack that needs a list of subnet IDs.  There is no example or documentation for something like this that I can find after a long search in vain: there are hundreds of Python classes in this library whose documentation is extremely difficult to navigate for someone who's new to AWS CDK.  I can concatenate the subnet IDs into a string and then split them in the other stack, but that seems ridiculous.

What is the correct way to export a value that is more general than a string from one stack to be used in another stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't output a list, only strings, I would iterate over the `vpc.private_subnets`

```
for idx, subnet in vpc.private_subnets:
    CfnOutput(self, f"private_subnet{idx}", values=subnet)
```

You mentioned you want to use this in another stack. If you implementing nested stacks I would,'t use this approach as you can just pass the Vpc object into your nested stacks so
`compute_stack = ComputeStack(self, "ComputeStack", vpc=vpc_stack.vpc)` and then call `ec2.SubnetSelection`

If you're set on using outputs and want to reference them in other stacks look at using `from_look_up`